# How many two letter words can be formed from 26 English letters?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

There are 26 English letters(a-z).

From layman approach, How can one calculate the possible two letter words from these 26 English letters?

Comment: Imagine making a complete list, ordered alphabetically. On the first line, list all the words that begin with a. We get aa, ab,ac, and so on up to az. So there are $26$ words on the first line. On the second line, list all the words that begin with b, so ba, bb, bc, and so on. The second line has $26$ words. On the third line, list the $26$ words that begin with c. And so on. We have $26$ lines, each of which has $26$ words, for a total of $(26)(26)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 26 choices for the first letter. For every choice of first letter there are 26 choices for the second letter. Thus there are 26 times 26 of them in total, or 676.

Comment: you mean for every letter, there are 26 choices. For example a, b, c: aa ab ac | ba bb bc | ca cb  cc. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that's the idea.

Comment: No that's wrong. There aren't 26 letters left for the second letter there are 25 since you already combined the first letter and the second letter.

Comment: The OP is allowing us to repeat letters, as in, "aa".

Comment: @Aleksandar Now I understood, why math is dangerous for brain? if it is swallowed improperly. Just kidding!!!

Comment: @MoseWintner I know that but it is still incorrect, you don't square it. There is a combinatorics formula. I removed my correct answer due to the number of downvotes.

Comment: @Aleksandar Learning combinatorics is not good for health.

Comment: @overexchange What?

Comment: It is not the combination formula you used. That is used when choosing k things from n things without replacement. I we were so choosing two letters from the 26-letter alphabet, we would never get words like "aa".

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming we're not talking about which ones are actual words.

There are 26 possibilities for the first letter and 26 for the second. Multiply them and you get 676 total possible "words" (but this includes things like ZQ and XT.)

If you want actual words, [this site](http://www.trussel.com/scrabble/2words.htm) says there are 96 in the OSPD4, the Scrabble dictionary.

And if you want a better estimate, there are 6 vowels and 20 consonants (counting Y as a vowel). They can go in either order (so we can have words like OF). 6 times 20 times 2 is 240 possible words.

Comment: yup ZQ  AA  XT  are considered, as per the context.

Comment: @overexchange Well, "aa" is an actual word - it's a type of lava. (I think it comes from Hawaiian, but I'm not sure.)

Answer (score 1):

$$
\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c}
\text{alphabetical order: } & aa & ba & ca & da & ea & fa & \cdots \\
& ab & bb & cb & db & eb & fb & \cdots \\
& ac & bc & cc & dc & ec & fc & \cdots \\
& ad & bd & cd & dd & ed & fd & \cdots \\
& ae & be & ce & de & ee & fe & \cdots \\
& af & bf & cf & df & ef & ff & \cdots \\
& ag & bg & cg & dg & eg & fg & \cdots \\
& \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots &  
\end{array}
$$
26 columns; 26 in each column.

Answer (score 0):

More generally the formula is:

$x^y$

where $x$ is the number of items in the set (26 possible letters in this case), and $y$ is the number of occurrences of that set of items (series of 2 letters in this case).

So,

1 letter (A) = $26^1 = 26$

2 letters (AA) = $26^2 = 26*26 = 676$

3 letters (AAA) = $26^3 = 26 * 26 * 26 = 17,576$

4 letters (AAAA) = $26^4 = 26 * 26 * 26 * 26 = 456,976$

etc.